# Difference between 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount' and 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudStorageAccount' classes in terms of usage?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-diagnostics

After upgrading from Azure SDK 1.7 => 1.8, we're noticing that there are two classes of essentially the same thing:

`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount` (v1.7)
`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudStorageAccount` (v1.8)

Before we migrate over to 1.8 in code (we can still reference Azure SDK 1.7 and compile), does anyone know what the newer benefits are and if there is some sample code to use it? This is from the perspective of Azure Diagnostics, so start and stop On-Demand transfers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage namespace is introduced with Storage Client Library 2.0, which comes with Azure SDK 1.8. But the Storage Client Library 1.7 also exists in SDK 1.8 for backward compatibility reasons. For more information on Storage Client Library 2.0, please refer to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/introducing-windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-for-net-and-windows-runtime.aspx).